# Software for internal url shortening and redirects

Tags: url-rewriting, dns

I want to build an internal url service for our research lab where you can create custom urls and reference them by simply typing

```
lab/<my-url>
```

in the address bar. (This would ONLY be accessible on the local network)

For instance, to link to some spreadsheet for lunch orders, one could create a url:

```
lab/lunch
```

This question has two parts:

1. How do I go about doing the url redirection without affecting normal internet traffic?
2. Are there existing software I can use for the management of the domain names?

Answer (score 1):

If you have control over the computers on your network, you could modify their `hosts` file.  [Wikipedia has a list of locations for this file.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file))

You could set up a mapping for `lab` to go to the server that's hosting this shortcut system, and then set up some software for redirecting there.  That would avoid having to mess around with DNS at all, but it would only work on systems that have the new `hosts` file set up properly.

As for actually setting up the server that does the redirection, I don't know of any software off the top of my head.  It would be fairly simple to do in Ruby on Rails, depending on your experience level.

Comment: Thanks! Given that I want to use the same server that also serves our public website, I can't just map 'lab' to the IP address of the server. Do I then use a subdomain? Or a different port?

Comment: The ``hosts`` file only allows you to bypass DNS and insert your own IP address.  If the redirect service were listening on a different port, the users would have to specify that port.  So you'd definitely want something listening on port 80.  You could potentially have the server hosting your external site and the internal site listen on two different IP addresses, and handle one differently than the other.